# How to propery design common settings

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

Business requirement for this desktop application is that common filter options exist on some views. That means that for those views that contain common filter options, if I check some option on one view, every other view that contains it will also needs to check the same option (many views will already be shown, so need to update those).

```
CommonSettings { CommonSetting1, CommonSetting2, CommonSetting3, CommonSetting4, CommonSetting5  }
ScreenASettings {ScreenASetting1, ScreenASetting2, CommonSetting2, CommonSetting4 }
ScreenBSettings {ScreenASetting1, CommonSetting1, CommonSetting2, CommonSetting3 }
// and so on
```

This settings need to be saved in file for later reading. The idea is, when screen opens this settings are applied. If both ScreenA and ScreenB are opened, and I change CommonSetting2 on ScreenA, ScreenB should also apply new value for this setting, since it also contains it.

My current design is this:
- only one instance of CommonSettings exists
- I have CommonSettingsViewModel, which contains reference to CommonSettings instance. CommonSettingsViewModel handles everything: showing options on screen (exposes common settings to CommonSettingsView, saves common settings, loads common settings, etc)
- Each CustomViewModel that contains custom and common settings will (through DI) get reference to CustomSetting and CommonSettingViewModel instances. This way it can pass control of creating common settings to CommonSettingViewModel, and deal only with its custom settings (load, save)

With this approach I have split responsibility for custom and common settings. One drawback that I see here is, when I need to query for data, I always need to pass both CustomSettings and CommonSettings instances, where I require both.

Do you find this approach correct, or you think there is a better one?

**Edit:** here is the current implementation I use for settings

```
public interface ISettings {
    string ElementPath { get; set; }
    Exception Error { get; }
    object GetValue(string setting);
    bool HasError { get; }
    void Read();
    void Save();
    void SetValue(string setting, object value);
}

// base class for ScreenASettings, CommonSettings, etc
public abstract class SettingsBase : ISettings { ... }

// ancestor class only needs to add settings
public class CommonSettings : BaseSettings {
    private bool _ommonSetting1;
    [Setting]
    public bool CommonSetting1 { .... }
    // CommonSetting2, CommonSetting3, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not define a common interface like so:

```
public interface ISettings
{
    T GetSetting<T>(string key);
    bool TryGetSetting<T>(string key, out T result);
}
```

You can then accept `ISettings` as a parameter to any of your functions, and use the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to define a `CompositeSettings` object that can represent multiple other `ISettings` objects:

```
public class CompositeSettings : ISettings
{
    private IEnumerable<ISettings> settings;
    public CompositeSettings(params ISettings[] settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public T GetSetting<T>(string key)
    {
        T result;
        if (TryGetSetting<T>(key, out result))
            return result;
        throw KeyNotFoundException(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetSetting<T>(string key, out T result)
    {
        foreach (var setting in this.settings)
        {
            T innerResult;
            if (setting.TryGetSetting<T>(out innerResult))
            {
                result = innerResult;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

(Now that I read back over this, perhaps my namings weren't completely helpful... probably `ISettingsProvider` is clearer)

Comment: So, if I understand you completely, what you are suggesting is to convert the strongly typed settings (ScreenASettings and CommonSettings) into KeyParValue settings, and then combine custom and common settings into one UEnumerable? Would not that later introduce magis strings, which are meant to cause possible problems?

Comment: I didn't go into how my sertings classes are designed, but I have one base class that does reading/writing to an xml file. This class will enumerate all properties on it, and if it finds a particular attriubte (SettingAttribute), it will consider that property to be a setting. So all setting classes will inherit from this class, and just declare their properties. THis way I do not use anywhere property names as strings.

Comment: Usually a 'setting' is a key and value - for instance `(string, int) Height` where the value for the string "Height" is an integer that denotes the height of the window. Are you saying you have a separate class for each setting?

Comment: My suggestion is that `ScreenASettings` and `CommonSettings` both implement the `ISettings` interface and expose methods to retrieve (and possibly set) a setting. You can then combine them in a `CompositeSettings` object which allows you to pass through settings transparently to any object that requires them.

Comment: ScreenASettings and CommonSettings currently implement SettingsBase class, which is an abstract class that provides Read/Save methods. All ancestors that inherit SettingsBase class just need to declare properties that they expose, and nothing else. SetingsBase will make sure that those properties are read/saved into a file, through reflection. What I do not understand is what will I get with combining ScreenASettings and CommonSettings into IEnumerable<ISetting>. Lets say that one setting is DateFrom. Key="StartDate", Value=Today. In the repository that gets data, I would need to write:

Comment: ...where x.StartDate == Settings["StartDate"] and... I do not see how this improves the design? Now instead of passing two parameters we pass one, but now we need to use magic strings for all settings while querying for data. What I need to do now is: ...where x.StartDate == commonSettings.StartDate and... Are you suggesting to use hard-coded strings, just to reduce passing parameters from two to one?

Comment: I think we have our wires crossed somewhere, I thought that the CommonSettings class was an aggregation of your settings in dictionary format. Can you please update the question with your interfaces/abstract classes and a use case for an example setting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28092/discussion-between-alex-g-and-goran)

Comment: sorry I was not at computer. Are you free now?